# How to execute once and expect multiple changes with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-expectations

If I want to test, that an operation produces certain side-effects, how can I execute the operation once and use the `change` rspec matcher. Example:

```
expect { some_method }.to change(Foo, :count).by(1)
expect { some_method }.to change(Bar, :count).by(1)
expect { some_method }.to change(Baz, :count).by(1)
```

How can I execute `some_method` only once, instead of 3 times?

Or do I need to do something like:

```
foo_count_before = Foo.count
bar_count_before = Bar.count
baz_count_before = Baz.count

some_method

foo_count_after= Foo.count
bar_count_after= Bar.count
baz_count_after= Baz.count

expect(foo_count_after - foo_count_before).to eq 1
expect(bar_count_after - bar_count_before).to eq 1
expect(baz_count_after - baz_count_before).to eq 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join multiple expectations together using [compound expectations](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/compound-expectations). In your example, this can look like this:

```
expect { some_method }
  .to change(Foo, :count).by(1)
  .and change(Bar, :count).by(1)
  .and change(Baz, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, a brand new article on the subject:     https://robots.thoughtbot.com/chain-rspec-matchers-for-improved-test-readability?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: Brilliant! I make a code cleaner. Thank you very much 